# Caluclate total of null, empty string, undefined in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I have an array like this below

`const userArray = ['school', 'science', '', '', null, 'bachelors', 'final', undefined, null]`

As you can notice, i have 2 empty string, 2 null and 1 undefined in it. So the total is 5.

how can i loop through each time and still get total count of empty string, null and undefined in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Array filter**.

```js
const userArray = [
  "school",
  "science",
  "",
  "",
  null,
  "bachelors",
  "final",
  undefined,
  null,
];
let ret = userArray.filter((x) => !x).length;
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: can you also specify please how did u find out null "" and undefined. How  does !Boolean(x)) || [] help for this

Comment: when casting null, undefined and empty string to boolean its always returns false and I used empty array if there is no boolean false item it will return zero.

Comment: @RaviK `|| []` isn’t part of that expression, and `!Boolean(x)` is equivalent to `!x`. See the [documentation about falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: @user4642212 you are right. Do not need use empty array because if no elements pass the test array filter method returns an empty array.

Comment: @mrhr- i get an eslint error where it says Redundant Boolean call for this code !Boolean(x))

Comment: @Ravi K you are right. I just used it to make it readable. Check the code now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Array.prototype.filter() method in order to remove the non falsy values from the array and calculate the length of the filtered array like below:

```js
const userArray = ["school", "science", "", "", null, "bachelors", "final", undefined, null];
  
const filteredArray = userArray.filter(value => !value);
console.log(filteredArray.length);
```